# What are we reviewing in the CV queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

[image: Screenshot]

On one hand, it asks specifically if the question should be closed as **primarily opinion-based**. The button hover-text agree by saying "disagree with this close vote" and "agree with this close vote" (a pluralization bug).

On the other hand, it says in the bullet points to **Leave Open** if the question shouldn't be closed and **Close** (which brings up the close dialog with *all reasons*) if the question should be closed for any reason. **Edit** "so that it does not need to be closed".

I always thought I was reviewing the *question*, not the existing closevotes, but noticed this after [Anna Lear disagreed in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/what-are-we-reviewing-in-the-cv-queue).

So which am I supposed to review? And can the ambiguity be fixed?

Comment: This is only a problem for computer programmers.  The average person knows what the question "Do you want to take out the trash?" means; programmers always answer "no."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess it's too bad that this is posted on MSO.

Comment: For reference, the first message in the linked chat conversation is in reply to [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2122686#2122686).

Comment: For reference, the question in question appears to be [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5073292).  You can tell me if I'm wrong.  You reviewed it the same way everyone else did, so I don't know why you're confused.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It looked border-line too broad, so I asked chat if I reviewed it right. Then too broad isn't a valid option? o.O

Comment: As you've already pointed out, the instructions say "Select **recommend closure** if the post should be closed for **any reason.**  It's not too broad.  Not even close.  Too Broad is for questions that require the better part of a book chapter to answer (i.e. extended tutorial questions), or can have many possible answers (i.e. Big List questions).

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, http://i.stack.imgur.com/qgdp5.png It asked about primarily opinion based.

Comment: That is there because someone voted to close the question as "primarily opinion-based."  The review is asking if you agree with him.  In the meantime, you can still evaluate a post as being off-topic for other reasons.

Comment: @bjb568 You might want to include more information next time you ask for a sanity check in chat. "Is my review correct?" in no way conveys that you thought the question might be too broad. But I guess this at least explains the confusion I had.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, that's what I thot. So I'm reviewing the post, good.

Comment: Yes, you're reviewing the post, not answering the question that the review poses.  I suppose that could be made clearer.

Comment: @AnnaLear I was thinking my review was "Leave Open" -> "No Action Needed" -> "Closure is inappropriate". But next time I'll be more specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no ambiguity (outside of your question).

When you visit /review/close, you're given a post and asked a question: "Should this question be closed as: *reason*?"

[image: Should this question be closed as: primarily opinion-based]

**This is *not* a simple yes/no question.** There are multiple potential answers, detailed in the instructions:

- **No,** it should be left open.
- **Yes** it should be closed for the reason stated.
- **Yes** it should be closed, but for a different reason.
- **No,** it should be edited instead.
- **I don't know** and want to review a different question.

I don't think that's so hard. But...

### Chat sucks for communication sometimes

...this got confusing in chat because [you asked an entirely *different* question](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2122686#2122686) (which you neglected to include in the bookmarked transcript you linked to:

[image: Is my review correct?]

At this point, confusion arose because *Anna couldn't see your review* - she just saw the review *task* that you'd reviewed. In other words, you asked her to validate your answer to a question but instead of showing her your answer you showed her the question - so, no doubt trying to be helpful, she gave you *her* answer to the that question.

Confused by her response, the conversation went downhill from there... All of this could've been avoided, if you'd just compared *your* review to *her* review - at which point the answer to *your* question would've been obvious:

[image: the reviews were the same]

"Yes."

Comment: *"No it should be left open"* is the one I chose. Which means I didn't choose *"Yes it should be closed for the reason stated"*, *"Yes it should be closed, but for a different reason"*, *"No it should be edited"*, or *"I don't know and want to review a different question"*. Which means I was asking if the other ones were actually incorrect choices. I don't think *that's* so hard… She then described CV review as if it were reviewing flags, accept or decline, which was confusing since there wasn't an accept or decline option…

Comment: BTW, what is *with* the crappy subpixel rendering in your screenshots? :P

Comment: None of that information was in your question though, @bjb. You might've avoided the confusion by just asking, "I responded 'leave open' here, is that correct? Or should I have closed it as 'too broad'?" (Since that appears to have been your specific concern) And Chrome on Windows does that; not as bad as fuzzy Mac screenshots, but not great.

Comment: @bjb568 You seem to be interpreting what was essentially a side comment on my part ("I don't see how that's opinion-based") as a different approach to review. I'll try to be more clear next time.

Comment: NOOOO Mac subpixel rendering is the beeest! Yeah, I could have communicated better I guess. (Is that a button to ban a mod? Shiny)

Comment: @AnnaLear *That*, followed by `The question was up for review as "primarily opinion-based"`.

Comment: Eh, by the  time we hit the screenshot part of that conversation we were already working under two different sets of assumptions.

Comment: It also says: "**Close** if this question should be closed for any reason;"

Comment: *Ahem*, **black** circle? **-1**.